# how to inject a service in to a command that uses another service inside?

Tags: php, symfony

I am kind of new to symfony2.

I have a service controller that called CURLController,
another controller that i have called myController uses that curl controller as a service to create curl requests.
I use  `$this->getContainer()->get('cont.my')` to call it.

Now i want to add a symfony command that get some vars from the command line and passes it to myController, so i wrote myController as a service as well (cont.my) and i call it from the command using  `$this->container->get('cont.my')`.

It works from the command and i do get in to the myController functions, but the problem is that the service inside it doesnt work any more.

What am i doing wrong?

The error i receive is :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

service.yml:

```
services:
utils.curl:
    class: project\CommonBundle\Controller\UtilsCurlController
cont.my:
        class: project\ServerBundle\Controller\MyController
```

myCommand :

```
class myCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand{
protected function configure(){
    $this->setName('mycommand:execute')
         ->setDescription('create a pull request');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){

    $serverResponse = $this->getContainer()->get('cont.my');
    $output->writeln(sprintf('<comment>'.$serverResponse->printHello().'</comment>'));
}
```

}

MyController:

```
class MyController extends Controller{

public function printHello(){
    $serverResponse = $this->container->get('utils.curl')
        ->setUrl('example.com')
        ->createCurl();
    return $serverResponse;
}
```

}

edit :

if fix it by adding :

```
calls:
          - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

to services.yml.
But why did it did the trick i dont get it.

Comment: Symfony controllers need access to the container.  The container is passed to the controller using the setContainer method.  Doing so leaves the constructor free for other stuff.  By the way, most of time you would not access a controller from a command.  Instead, try to do what you need to do using just utils.curl or maybe making yet another service class to which utils.curl is injected.  Your controller and your command would then share this new service class.

Comment: The container consept is like a scope?
What is the Best Practice to do what i need?

Comment: No.  Containers are not scopes.  Consider reading the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: I did read it but still didn't got it .
Then i saw this youtube video and got it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKD2-MAkXyQ

thanks: )

Comment: The controller already has the service container injected in it, whereas the commands do not. To add the container to a command you can do it the way you did, or you could have say class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand like in the docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Comment: Can i have more then one container in my symfony project and if the answer is yes, then way?